# creating chart in Visual Studio 2013 using objects field data in c++

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-studio-2013, gnuplot

First of all since my c++ project is too large to share, I'll post it here as a similar,simple one.  Now, I have a *node Class* and all node objects contain a float field with name *cpu_time*. To illustrate it :

```
   class node
    {
      public:

         void setCputime(float val){this->cpu_time=val;}
         void setName(string name){this->name=name;}
         float getCpuTime(){return this->cpu_time;}
          // some other methods here
      private:
        float cpu_time=-1;
        string name;
    };
```

In my main function, I've create finite number of node object and assign some float number to its cpu_time field.

For example:

```
   #include <iostream> 
   #include <vector>
   int main()
   {
      vector<node *> myNodes;
      for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
      {
         node * temp= new node;
         temp->setCpuTime((float)i);
         temp->setName("different names will be assigned for each of them");
         myNodes.push_back(temp);
       }
   }
```

Note that, in my real project I've made different things but as a result I'll have a node pointer vector like *myNodes*.

Now,at this point my question begins, I need to create UI for my project and in this UI, I need to create a chart x-axis will be time and y-axis will be name of node. However, I have no experience with UI before. I've used Visual Studio 2013 so far and I also heard that I can create UI using Visual Studio too.

Is there anyone  who can say how to do it or show me some tutorials?I've tried to find it on Google but since my english is not well enough I guess I did not write the correct keywords. Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*

After creating this chart, I need to click any point on chart and make some process on it.

*EDIT 2*

I need to do it using Visual Studio

***EDIT 3*
After some searches on web, I've found DISLIN and gnuplot libraries. Is there anyone who have any experience with them ?**

*EDIT 4*

Still could not found the way to achive this.

Comment: `I need to do it using Visual Studio` BTW Qt is a c++ library that compiles fine under Visual Studio. You do not need to switch to QtCreator or use mingw. Although with that said you most likely have to build your applications in the frameworks that your team uses.

Comment: @drescherjm yeap you're right but they do not want to include qt into the project and the reason for that it causes some debugging problems according to them.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you look at [Qt framework.](http://qt-project.org/) . This framework is cross-platform. Once you are familiar with the UI framework you can integrate [QCustomplot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/) widget with your project. The component comes with built in samples.Qt also comes with a visual studio [add-in](http://qt-project.org/downloads). This allows you to use Visual Studio for development. Everything will be inside visual Studio. It is very easy to install and configure

Comment: thanks for information. I forgot to mention that QT framework is not an option since my project is a group of work and my team wants to do it using visual studio